# How to update a column in sql from another column and row in same table dynamicaly

Tags: mysql, sql-server, select, sql-update

```
update pos 
set a = concat_ws((select b from (select * from pos where a is not null limit 1) as ta), '', b)
where a is null
```

I want to update `every row` in column `a` from `last value` of `b` and its value of `b`.

Comment: Thats very confusing, provide some sample data and expected result after the update.

Comment: and choose either mysql or sql-server

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, and you're using SQL Server, then you're looking for `LAG()` function to get previous value of `B`. Figure out how to use that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

> Accesses data from a previous row in the same result set without the
>   use of a self-join in SQL Server 2012. LAG provides access to a row at
>   a given physical offset that comes before the current row. Use this
>   analytic function in a SELECT statement to compare values in the
>   current row with values in a previous row.